# Laurent Series Expansion of $\dfrac{z^2}{z^2-1}$ about $z_0=1$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

So, as the question states, I'm trying to find the Laurent series expansion of $\dfrac{z^2}{z^2-1}$ about $z_0=1$.

---

I've tried fiddling with geometric series stuff (the form of the rational function makes me want to), but I have to keep reminding myself that that won't work because we're trying to get the series expansion about $z_0=1$, not $z_0=0$.

I've also noticed that it can be put in the form

$$\left(\frac{z^2}{z+1}\right)\frac{1}{z-1}$$

And so in that form all I'd have to do is find the series expansion of $\dfrac{z^2}{z+1}$ about $z_0=1$, and that doesn't seem to be any easier.

And finally, I've also tried to use partial fractions on it

$$\frac{z^2}{z^2-1}=\frac{z^2}{2}\left(\frac{1}{z-1}-\frac{1}{z+1}\right)$$

But still, that doesn't seem to help much.

---

Could you please give me some direction here?

Comment: $$\frac{z^2}{z^2-1} = \frac{1}{z-1}\cdot \frac{((z-1)+1)^2}{2+(z-1)}$$

Comment: To add a hint to Daniel's: $\frac{1}{2 + u} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{1} {1 + \frac{u}{2}} =  \frac{1}{2} (1 - \frac{u}{2} + (\frac{u}{2})^2 - \ldots)$.